# Can we use bind variable in dbms.sql.parse to avoid sql injection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, checkmarx

We get checkmarx vulnerability wherever we use dbms.sql.parse. When I check online, bind variables can be used to avoid sql injection however, can we use bind variable in ddl statements?

Please guide me in this

Thanks

wherever we use concatenation, it throws sql injection vulnerability, and also all of them are ddl command.

Let me give the sample one,

```
Procedure (userid in varchar2)
is
  v_sqlstatement VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_cursor INTEGER;
  v_return INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_cursor := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
  v_sqlstatement := 'DROP USER ' || pp_userid;
  DBMS_SQL.parse (v_cursor, v_sqlstatement, DBMS.SQL.native);
END;
```

Comment: and where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Bind variables aren't a thing in DDL statements.  My guess is you want the `dbms_assert` package (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_ASSERT.html#GUID-2FEC43E1-F656-4A6D-BC29-880F89D931E7) but a reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added sample from the actual code, here instead concatenating userid, can we use bind variable? If not, what is the alternative solution.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/System-Packages/ExecutingPLSQLBlocksanduseBINDVARIABLEtobindvariable.htm maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, unless you are running 8i, you don't need `dbms_sql` for this. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is much more user-friendly.

Second, bind variables aren't used in DDL. You have to string together DDL and execute as dynamic SQL if you're doing it from PL/SQL.

As for the injection risk, the only risk you have is being asked to drop an important user you'd rather not drop. But that's not much of a risk, because as long as you don't add the "`CASCADE`" option (*don't!*), it will raise an error if someone asks it to drop a user with any objects. That's what you want. Users without objects are not important enough to be concerned about.

However, if you want a more secure pattern, then use the parameter to lookup users in the dictionary and compile the DDL entirely from your own lookups:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE drop_user(in_username IN varchar2)
AS
  var_username varchar2(128);
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(username)
    INTO var_username
    FROM dba_users
   WHERE username = in_username;

  IF var_username IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER "'||var_username||'"';
  END IF;
END;
```

This ensures that the parameter actually is a valid username. You'll also want to ensure they don't try to drop the procedure owner itself or it will hang.

Lastly, I would suggest rethinking the need for such a procedure altogether. Only a DBA should have the ability to drop users; why would they want to use a procedure to do so instead of simply issuing the DDL normally?

If it's *not* for DBA use, then you shouldn't leave it open-ended. Register in a secure table a list of usernames or username patterns it is allowed to drop and don't act on anything else. Restrict it to the required use-case as much as possible.

Comment: I have used execute immediate, but still i get sql injection checkmarx vulnerabilites cause of concatenation. please suggest

Comment: That would be a question for the checkmarx application. Just because it is flagging something doesn't mean it is a real vulnerability. They might be flagging any and all EXECUTE IMMEDIATE operations, which would be overkill. If that's the case you need to push back on management's expectation for the tool's accuracy.

Comment: Paul W, However, previously it was 15 vulnerabilites , Now it is reduced to 12 vulnerabilites after using execute immediate

Comment: Folks can't help you with this if the goal is to get a particular software product like checkmarx to give you an output you want. We can only help if the goal is to actually improve your PL/SQL code. The two can't be assumed to be the same. I wouldn't give too much credit to products like that. They can have you do all kinds of changes to code that are unnecessary.